# Entity is updated in database without calling persist()

Tags: validation, symfony, doctrine-orm

I found a little strange issue. I added some constrains to my entities and found out that the database were updated despite the constrain failed and the errormessage were shown.

So it is sure, that the entity does not pass the persist() or flush() method in controller.

That problem only appears with entities I've loaded from database before, not with new instances.

Is there some automatic save or something? There are some listeners who deal with other entities and they maybe call flush(), but why does this have effect to my not persisted entity?

Here is my test action. The manager only includes the errorhandling and accesscontrol, no more magic.

```
public function testAction()
{
    $object = $this->get('object.manager')->load(42);
    $object->setName('Test Autosave 2')
         ->setLabel('Test Autosave 2');

    return array();
}
```

Any ideas what causes that problem?

Answer (score 3):

If the `flush` method was called in any other place, entity fetched from a database will be saved automatically (without `persist`). The new entity won't saved if the method `persist` wasn't obviously called.

You can read in the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#updating-an-object):

> Notice that calling $em->persist(...) isn't necessary. Recall
>   that this method simply tells Doctrine to manage or "watch" the
>   ... object. In this case, since you fetched the ... object
>   from Doctrine, it's already managed.

Comment: Ok, but how can I prevent this behaviour? I need to load and change the entity in the update workflow and I also need control, whether update it or not, depending on validation. And I also have to save complete unrelated entities when a user calls a page.

Comment: I think you have to find where you call the `flush`.

Comment: How should that solve my problem? One entity is loaded, changed by userinput and validated with errors. That neccessary, because we want to show the data again in our form. At some other point in the application is a different and unrelated entity which does some stuff and it should be persisted and flushed.

So what is the benefit, if I have no longer control to save the data or not?

Comment: If fetched objects doesn't changed, they will not be saved to database again. Or do you want to change them, but not persist?

Comment: Of course, because thats default in generated edit/update actions. Load the entity by id, bind the formdata, validate and update or not, if there are invalid values.

Comment: We came to that with what began. 1) Find, where you calling the `flush` and don't call it, if form is not valid. 2) Perhaps you need to separate create/update actions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59409/discussion-between-daniel-and-galago).

Answer (score 2):

> An entity is detached from an EntityManager and thus no longer managed by invoking the EntityManager#detach($entity) method on it or by cascading the detach operation to it. Changes made to the detached entity, if any (including removal of the entity), will not be synchronized to the database after the entity has been detached.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities

I think you should detach your entity from manager so it will not update it on editing.

Comment: links expire with version updates... here is a basic code example: 
   
`$em->detach($entity);`